# Postfix configuration issue?

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix

I don't know if it is the right place to answer this question (please tell me I will remove it). I have an error message when using telnet to send an email to ab account I have specified in my postfix database (I am using ubuntu) :

```
451 4.3.0 <contact@localhost.fr>: Temporary lookup failure
```

when I look at my logs  I get this

```
unbuntu-v postfix/pickup[6798]: 3303850ACB: uid=118 from=<git>
Apr  3 22:18:48 unbuntu-v postfix/cleanup[8293]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_aliases.cf lookup error for "git@0.0.0.127.in.addr.arpa"
Apr  3 22:18:48 unbuntu-v postfix/cleanup[8293]: warning: 3303850ACB: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for git@0.0.0.127.in.addr.arpa -- deferring delivery
```

but in my 'comptes' postfix's table, I have a `contact@localhost.fr` email. And I don't know why my logs are referencing to a (indeed existing) `git` user. For information, here's my `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_aliases.cf` file

```
hosts = 127.0.0.1
user = postfix
password = euler;.
dbname = postfix
table = alias
select_field = destination
where_field = source
additional_conditions = AND etat=1
```

Could someone help ?